# Forcing $scope.$watch to only fire once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.$watch('text', function () {
    $scope.obj = new Text($scope.text);
    console.log('Hi!');
});

// Hi!
// Hi!
```

How can I prevent this $watch from firing multiple times?  I am not defining or changing `$scope.text` at any time before this snippet above.  I attempted to test `newValue !== oldValue` but this did not change anything.

**EDIT:**

I have narrowed down the issue to a directive issue.  The input box that is being watched is inside a custom directive, that is for some reason effecting the `ng-model` of the input box multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

`$scope.$watch(..)` returns a unbind function, so do this:

```
var unbind = $scope.$watch('text', function () {
    $scope.obj = new Text($scope.text);
    console.log('Hi!');
    unbind();
});
```

This will cause it to fire, and unbind itself after firing just once.

EDIT:

for only valueChanges:

```
$scope.$watch('text', function (nv, ov) {
     if (ov != nv) {
        $scope.obj = new Text($scope.text);
        console.log('Hi!');
     }
    });
```

Comment: Wait- I want it to fire once per time when the *value of $scope.text actually changes*.  Will this unbind the `$watch` for good?

Comment: Use newValue and oldValue for that, like I showed you

Comment: As I said, I tried comparing `ov` and `nv` and it does not work.  console.log is still fired twice inside the conditional.

Comment: Directive issue:  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807858/in-a-directive-watch-fires-two-times-reverting-newvalue-to-the-original-pre-w for more info.  Attempting to troubleshoot.

Comment: @DavidXu Can you please explain how the `unbind` works? why is the `$watch` executed if you're setting the `unbind` as a variable variable?